# OptionMenu widget not updating when StringVar is changed until hovered

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need a menu that can respond to items being clicked by running code then switch the text back to a default text.

Currently, my implementation works but the default text is only displayed when the cursor hovers over the menu after clicking.

I have searched but I could not find anything related to this problem, although maybe that is because I am unsure as to what exactly is causing this.

Here is the code to reproduce this behaviour:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

default_text = 'select an item'

def thing_selected(self, *args):
    #other stuff happens here
    var.set(default_text)

var = StringVar(root)
var.set(default_text)
var.trace('w', thing_selected)

menu = OptionMenu(root, var, *['Pizza','Lasagne','Fries','Fish'])
menu.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Here is a gif representing the outcome:
[image: gif]

I would expect the text at the top to be updated instantaneously, but it only updates when the cursor has hovered over the widget

I am looking for some way to trigger a hover event on the widget or I am open to suggestions for any other methods of accomplishing this.

Comment: Changing the value of a Tkinter var from within a write trace on the same var is problematic - this would be an infinite loop, if write traces weren't automatically disabled for the duration (including the one that actually updates the widget).  Try `root.after(1, var.set, default_text)` to delay the change until you're no longer inside the write trace.  You will probably need to modify `thing_selected()` to ignore this specific change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a different route and use the `command` attribute of the `OptionMenu`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

default_text = 'select an item'

def thing_selected(selected):
    #other stuff happens here
    print(var.get())
    var.set(default_text)
    print(var.get())

var = tk.StringVar()
var.set(default_text)

options = ['Pizza','Lasagne','Fries','Fish']
menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *options, command = thing_selected)
menu.pack()

root.mainloop()
```